# Opening a NTFS partition fails with report: Not authorised

Tags: 11.10, mount, ntfs

Besides lesser errors on 11.10, I ran into a more annoying one: I cannot access NTFS partitions. No matter whether I use nautilus, dolphin, tux commander or archive manager, always does the same thing, could not mount 'disc name': Not authorised'

There were several fixes of problems with access to NTFS partitions, but none of them helped. When I used nautilus in sudo mode, the partition looked empty, although when I booted on windows, there were files. It was reported as a bug somewhere.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use NTFS-config and it mounts all me external and internal drives with write capabilities

Install Ntfs-Config

```
sudo apt-get install ntfs-config
```

just run this in commandline after installing

```
sudo mkdir -p /etc/hal/fdi/policy
```

this will make ntfs config run and u can enable read write

Run NTFS Config from dash and have it auto configured your windows drive

this sshould help you access your ntfs partition

Comment: please mark it as answered by clicking on the tick mark
and upvoting it

Comment: I ticked it as answered, but I cannot vote up, I don't have 15 reputation.

Answer (score 0):

After some googling, I found that a fix for this problem and also to many other problems I am having and for sure many others is:

```
sudo apt-get remove lightdm && sudo apt-get install gdm
```